# Sending text file output to email in table, but email out has repeated lines in table based on text file lines

Tags: linux, email

Working on below to send txt file out to email in table. Email out has repeated lines of command based on number of lines in txt file out. Why the output receiving email has repeating number of lines as from text file ? Also how to use 2nd row from txt file to output.

Using below.

```
tmpfile="/tmp/tmp.html"
 input="/tmp/tmp.txt"
 awk 'BEGIN {print "<table>"}
 {print "<tr>";print "<td>Hostname</td>";print "<td>"NR==2{print $0}"</td>";print "</tr>"}
  END {print "</table>"}' "$input" >"$tmpfile"
```

```
Expected out in email (table):
Hostname    machineipaddress
```

```
Current out:
Hostname    NR==2{print $0}
Hostname    NR==2{print $0}
```

```
# cat /tmp/tmp.txt
machinename.domain
machineipaddress
```

Comment: 1. Why are you using awk for this?  A while read loop with `printf` statements would work better.  or a heredoc. 2. Why are you making awk read /tmp/test.txt when you're not even using any of the data from it? (BTW, this is the source of your repeated output - except from the `END{ }` block each awk statement is executed for every input line).

Comment: 3. How a html table is rendered depends on the web client (e.g. browser) - if you want prettily formatted lines and vertical bars then either print them as plain text yourself (e.g. with printf) or pipe the html table through a text-mode web client - e.g. `links` with the  `-dump`  option.   4. You don't need a tempfile for this.  just print things to stdout in the order you need them (e.g. From: and To: headers and a blank line first, then the message body) and pipe the output into `sendmail -t`

Comment: Grebbing the lines from /tmp/test.txt file (which I missed to add it ). My output is still getting repeated, based on number lines in test.txt file.

Comment: `{
 tmpfile="/tmp/test.html"
 input="/tmp/test.txt"
 echo '<html><body><table border=1>'>"$tmpfile"
 awk '{print "<tr>""<td>hostname</td>""<td>"$1"</td>";print "</tr>"}{print "<tr>";print "<td>date</td>""<td>"$2"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table></body></html>"}' "$input" >> "$tmpfile"`

Comment: yes. awk is doing exactly what you're telling it to, producing one table row ( `<tr>...<tr>`) for each line of input.   If you want help with your script, please show sample (anonymised if necessary) input, and sample expected output.   Also, **ask an actual question** - all you have posted is a statement about your script....what, exactly is the problem? what, exactly, do you want to know?

Comment: `code in backticks`

Comment: Below is the script used.                                                                                                    
 `tmpfile="/tmp/test.html"
 input="/tmp/test.txt"
 awk 'BEGIN {print "<table>"}
 {print "<tr>";print "<td>Hostname</td>";print "<td>"NR==2{print $0}"</td>";print "</tr>"}
  END {print "</table>"}' "$input" >"$tmpfile"`

Comment: Output for the above command:                                                                                                                   `Hostname NR==2{print $0}
Hostname NR==2{print $0}
Hostname NR==2{print $0}
Hostname NR==2{print $0}`                                                                         
/tmp/txt.txt has output of four lines  and script also printing four lines, even though the command is to print one row. This is the issue . Why the number of lines printed based on output of text file lines.Still figuring to use awk for 2nd line of the file  .

Comment: edit any updates to your question into the question, don't post in comments.  nobody's gonna make any effort to read an unreadable mess.   also, don't just describe your sample input and output.  Show it. With actual sample files.  Descriptions are subject to interpretation mistakes.  Samples are not.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- If you only want output for the 2nd line of input, then use that (`NR==2`) as the condition for the entire block of awk code.
- Also, you don't need so many print statements - you can simplify it (and make it much easier to read and modify) down to just one.  Note in the script below that only the `$0` in the print statement is unquoted.
- You can print the initial `<table>` and `</table>` in the shell script, before and after awk.  There's nothing wrong with doing that with BEGIN and END blocks in the awk script, but since they're just simple print statements (i.e. there's no processing that requires awk - BEGIN is usually used to set up initial variables and other conditions for an awk script, and END is usually used to produce the final output - e.g. a summary or the results of all the processing in the rest of the script, or just a total or average), it's easier to do them outside of awk. More importantly, it simplifies the awk script.

```
tmpfile='/tmp/tmp.html'
input='/tmp/tmp.txt'

{
  echo '<table>'
  awk 'NR==2 { print "<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>"$0"</td></tr>" }' "$input"
  echo '</table>'
} > "$tmpfile"
```

output:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.html
<table>
<tr><td>Hostname</td><td>machineipaddress</td></tr>
</table>
```

- Finally, add newlines and indentation to your code to make it readable.  A tiny awk (or whatever) script like this may often be called a "one-liner" but that doesn't mean it can only be on one line - it's in single quotes so can contain newlines.  It's almost impossible to read and make sense of extremely long lines of code, which means it's almost impossible to debug them.

  Rule of thumb: **add a newline after every statement**.

  It's not really relevant here because there's only one statement in the awk script but you should also **indent code** so that each nested block is indented a little more (a tab or a few spaces, but it should be consistent, each new indentation level should add the same amount of indentation) - this makes it easier to see the flow of the code.